# How to set last modified file?

Tags: android, android-file

i am trying set last modified of file on Android 5+ (API 21+).
I tried:
1. `File.setLastModified()` does not work on a lot of devices. Android bug. It returns `False`.
2. Shell command `touch` via `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd)` not work.
3. `Files.setLastModifiedTime()` returns Exception on some devices:

```
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Test/IMG_20181222_102357.jpg: Operation not permitted
```

,but `File` is writable: `Files.isWritable(f.toPath())` returns `True`.

Permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

RunTime permissions also implemented and allowed.

Could you help, how can I set last modified file on Android?

Comment: Do you have the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission? It could help your option 3.

Comment: Yes, i added to the question.

Comment: Do you need this for the entire File system or a specific folder (that your app creates)?

Comment: @ShishirShetty: for /storage/emulated/0/DCIM folder.